# node.js installation error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node-red. I already installed some missing dependencies when I encountered this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/node-red $ sudo node red.js
DEBUG: ERROR in file: /home/pi/node-red/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/utils.js / Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/pi/node-red/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/utils.js'
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: after removing all the node-red directories I managed to re-install it.

Comment: did you install then node module uglify? and is its folder at that location?

Comment: I did, thank you! Now it complains about /lib/WebSocket. I will install that too but I wonder if there's a way to install ALL the necessary dependencies rather than having to install them one by one?

Comment: Ok, just realised that all the dependencies are installed in the node_modules directory. Does it help if I add the directory to the $PATH?